# Eclipse Navigation Pane

Tags: eclipse

I would like to ask how to enable this feature in Eclipse where we have this toolbar in the editor area where you could see the project location of the active editor.

I don't have the graphical representation of it but it looks like having this following components: `Project Name > Package > File > Method`. It's not similar with the `Java Browsing Perspective`. It's more of a mini-outline of the file active in the editor which is commonly found in the middle of the textarea and the tabs in the editor area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the "Toggle Breadcrumb" button with a little green C and a little black triangle. It's on the toolbar. In the screenshot here just below "PDFs".

[image: Toolbar shot]

Comment: @ Dr.Java : Right click on the file contents and select "Show in Breadcrumb" option also to show it for the editor

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean "Outline"

Go to Window menu, Show View, Outline.

Comment: No. Not that. Is the one located just below the tab title of the active editor.